# Add auto number column to ListView on c#

Tags: c#, database, listview

I've a ListView that fetch data from API and parsed to object list. I want to add an auto number column in the list view.(I don't want the number to be saved in the database itself , I just want to sort the rows in the list view)
[MyListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeMBZ.png)

The code I'm using on controller :

```
 public void setBooking(List<ModelBooking> bookings)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> {
            bookingList.ItemsSource = bookings;
        });
    }
```

The code i'm using on Page:

```
<Grid Background="#FFF0F0F7">
    <Label Content="Antrian Booking" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF636363" FontSize="24"/>
    <ListView x:Name="bookingList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="258" Margin="45,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="710">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="Incremental Number Right here" Header="#" Width="40"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding first_name}" Header="NAME" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding repairment_note}" Header="PROBLEM" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding repairment_date}" Header="DATE" Width="110"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding service_name}" Header="SERVICE" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ACTION" Width="110"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Add "Id" style property and perform simple iteration to assign Id to each entry:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        var list = new List<Test>();
        list.Add(new Test { Name = "Zero" });
        list.Add(new Test { Name = "One" });
        list.Add(new Test { Name = "Two" });

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            list[i].Id = i;
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```